# if a topological space has only a finite number of points each of which is closed then it has the discrete topology

Tags: general-topology

This is exercise 2.6(c) from Kosniowski's A first course in algebraic topology:

*Show that if a topological space has only a finite number of points each of which is closed then it has the discrete topology*

My attempt:

Let $X$ be a topological space as mentioned. If $U$ is a subset of $X$ then it is closed. This implies it's complement is open. The complement is also a subset of $X$ and hence it is also closed. Therefore, double complement of $U$ is open which means $U$ is open.

My question is that why is there a restriction of finite number of points?

Comment: You want to show that the subset is closed. In general not every subset is closed.

Comment: You start with any subset $A$. Its complement is closed (because it’s also  finite, like $X$) so $A$ is open. Hence $X$ has the discrete topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If $U$ is a subset of $X$ then it is closed.

How do you know this? This is not true in general. For example, in $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology, there exist many sets which are subsets of $\mathbb R$ but not closed.

In your case, it is indeed true that all subsets of $X$ are closed. But you have to **prove** that they are closed, you cannot just write that down and hope for the best.

**Hint**:

To prove that $U$ is closed, you will have to use some specific properties of $X$.

---

Also, just a general piece of advice. Are you sure you want to tackle algebraic topology if you so far do not yet have a firm grasp on topology? I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: I clearly misunderstood the exercise. I thought "each of which is closed" meant every subset is supposed to be closed?

Comment: @user946582 "A finite number of points, each of which is closed" means that all singletons are closed.

Comment: @user946582 "Since all singletons are closed all singletons are open"... how do you know that? How do you know that a particular singleton is open?

Comment: another attempt: closed sets are closed under finite union and since every singleton is closed, every set is closed

Comment: @user946582 That's a much better attempt. Do you now also see why you are restricted to a finite number of points?

Comment: yes. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @user946582 My pleasure. Don't forget to accept this answer if it is what you needed :)